# Most efficient way to set TextView colour

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-color

What's the most efficient way to set the color of a `TextView` and why? Is there 1 method that is more memory and/or processor efficient? Or is there no difference at all to what happens with my app when it's running? Is it better to refer to a colour resource than declare RGB everytime I set a colour?

**Option 1 (using RGB channel)**

```
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(154,160,166))
```

**Option 2 (using colour parser)**

```
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2B3A11"))
```

**Option 3 (using colour resource from `colors.xml`)**

```
myTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.<name_of_colour>))
```

Comment: In my opinion option 1 is the most efficient, since the creation is very clear and done rapidly with the definition of three exact values. Options 2 and 3 require an extra step of computation. 2: needs to parse a string, 3: has to read from the resource file -> file read every time.

Comment: Does it matter which of these methods is faster? Whichever method is faster, is going to be by a fraction so small that you would be hard pressed to even measure it. You should be asking the question of "which is more readable and maintainable" instead. The answer is the 3rd one.

Comment: Option 4 - Save constants to constants, like `static final Color MY_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#2B3A11");` and use `myTextView.setTextColor(MY_COLOR);` (then you can amortize the cost, and use whichever you find most easy to read to set `MY_COLOR`).

Comment: If you have enough views on your screen for these to have any measurable difference in speed, you have much bigger problems to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 Should be the fastest way to set color to your TextView. With option 2 being a very closed Second. Because both RGB values and Hexcodes function in a similar way. It all comes down to the functions they are called from and how these functions are executed in the background (look [rgb](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)) [parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)) for these function's description and implementation  ). 
As
`myTextView.setTextColor(...)` is the same. So what happens to your textview in the background remains the same only the picking up of color is done differently.

Is it better to refer to a color resource than declare RGB everytime I set a color?

Ans-  It depends on the your own usage,for example 
if you want to use a color multiple times and find it harder to remember the rgb code then you should definitely save the color int the color resource and refer to it later. The color resource was created for this purpose only right! And as @Fancesc mentioned it does make your documents readable and maintainable. Hence, the more professional way of doing things.

On the other hand using rgb right whenever needed saves you a lot of trouble.

1. You don't need to save any data anywhere.
2. While using you don't need to search the whole color resource file.
3. 99% times the color model used is rgb/rgba, so everything you do ends up here.
4. Plus newer updates make it easier to work on rgb and hex values for colors. one such example is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeAhR.png).
5. Good for people who are bad with color names.

I am assuming you knew all of this already but decided to ask it anyways.XD. Have a good Day.

Comment: I’d highly advise against hard coding the value right where it’s used. This buries your constants in code all over the place, making it difficult to edit them. Very similar to the mistake of hard coding user-readable strings all over the place.

Comment: That's why i tried to give a neutral answer. I completely get your point. It's not a great way to hardcode values but its a way.